# I am trying to save my file on the c drive and im getting an error

Tags: java, file

```
package javaapplication33;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class JavaApplication33 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{


    File happyFile = new File("/happy.txt");
    if (happyFile.exists() == false) {
        happyFile.createNewFile();
        System.out.println("the file is created");
    } else {
        System.out.println("tHE FILE ALREADY EXSISTED   ");
     }
   }
 }
```

here is my error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883)
at javaapplication33.JavaApplication33.main(JavaApplication33.java:14)
```

Java Result: 1

- I tried C:// & C:/ it still did not work*

Comment: Did you try to a folder inside C:\ ? like C:\Temp, might be related to permissions (writing to root folder).

Comment: if it's not necessary , don't use C file because it need permission .

Comment: I think you need backslashes for windows, quite possibly two of them.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to write to a specific path in Windows, you need to use quoted backslashes:

```
 File happyFile = new File("c:\\mydir\\happy.txt");
```

To make the code generic you can use the path separator and home directory from the [system properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think "/happy.txt" is a valid windows file path. Try a path that always should be valid

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteToDisk {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tempdir");
        String separator = File.pathSeparator;
        File happyFile = new File(tempDir + separator + "happy.txt");
        if (!happyFile.exists()) {
            happyFile.createNewFile();
            System.out.println("the file is created");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("tHE FILE ALREADY EXISTED");
        }
    }
}
```

This prints "the file is created" the first time and "tHE FILE ALREADY EXISTED" any subsequent time.

Comment: `System.lineSeparator();` returns a linefeed `\n`, not a path separator ` \ `

Comment: This is the proper multi-platform solution +1